# Folders permissions is ressetting every time I boot my laptop

Tags: linux, permissions, arch-linux

I am using Arch Linux, and every time I boot my laptop as a user, the hard disk folders permissions is set to root only, so I can't open them as a user, I used the following command to change the permission

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /mnt
```

where /mnt is the folder that contains my hard disk. When I reboot my laptop, every thing resets and I had to use the same command to access my hard disk again, so how to save the permissions?

The output of /etc/fstab

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/sda6
UUID=e0888535-4d8b-4b89-9a7e-4a85208fe129   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1
```

My hard disk is a windows disk, I am dual booting with windows 10.

The output of df:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
dev              2973860         0   2973860   0% /dev
run              2982588       716   2981872   1% /run
/dev/sda6       30313412   4987780  23762752  18% /
tmpfs            2982588    101116   2881472   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2982588         0   2982588   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            2982588       220   2982368   1% /tmp
tmpfs             596516        24    596492   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sda4      354528216 350712252   3815964  99% /mnt
```

The output of mount:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=2973860k,nr_inodes=743465,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13513)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1001 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=596516k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001)
/dev/sda4 on /mnt type ntfs (rw,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)
```

Comment: Show the output of file `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Why is your hard disk mounted as `/mnt`? Is it a Windows disk? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott .. I edited the question

Comment: Thanks. It’s odd that your `/etc/fstab` doesn’t have an entry for `/mnt`. It might help if you added the output of `df` and `mount`. Does this problem happen when you just reboot Linux, or only when you go Linux → Windows → Linux? If it happens only when you boot Windows, I’d suspect that Windows is messing with it — especially if you have “fast boot” enabled. If the problem occurs even when you simply reboot Linux, I’d be concerned about the filesystem type (`df` and `mount` should show that). If it’s a Windows disk, it’s probably *not* `ext4`, and so it might not understand Unix permissions.

Comment: @Scott I've added the output of df and mount, answering your questions it happens when I just reboot linux, I used another Linux distros like ubuntu, and MX linux, and I just had to mount the disk (which is /dev/sda4), but in Arch Linux, it seems like I had to set the permissions my self.

Comment: OK; the important line is the last one, which shows that the filesystem type is `ntfs`. I don’t know what more to say; hopefully the information you’ve provided will be enough for somebody else to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to automate the chmod command at boot-time by adding it to  /etc/rc.local

**OR**:

Try to create SYSTEMD UNIT FILE in /etc/systemd/system/ directory. Call it addpermission.service for example.

Add this script into it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Adding permissions to users


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'sudo chmod -R 775 /mnt'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that enable it by running the script below:
`systemctl enable addpermission.service`

To test if it is working, you can remove the permission on the /mnt directory if you add it, try to start the unit file, and check it is status:

```
systemctl start addpermission.service 
systemctl status addpermission.service
```

if status is OK. Try to check then the permissions on the /mnt directory. if it's changed then try to reboot and check again, if not check the error and try to edit the command in  ExecStart to fix it. On my side, it worked.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this?, I don't have a file named rc.local

Comment: even /etc/rc.d/rc.local?

Comment: yes, just request-key.d and rc_keymaps that exists, and both are empty folders

Comment: I've created the rc.local file and enabled it, and it now works, but chmod or chown, takes a long time to finish executing, is there any other way to change permissions faster?

Comment: I have added a new way to solve this problem, you can try it

Comment: It is normal as you are changing permission on a large amount of file. For more info about solving this problem check this thread. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79868/chmod-recursive-permission-on-thousands-of-files

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue recently on few of servers, finally i fixed it be removing ACL.

So i would highly recommend you to check is that directory had any existing ACL setup.

You can find out using getfacl , if you see any ACL permissions, then remove it, that will fix this issue permanently.